# Django rest framework is providing the wrong parameters to custom permission class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I'm having an issue where Django Rest Framework's custom permission system is treating my custom permissions' methods like they are `classmethods` or `staticmethods`.

When hitting a breakpoint in the permission method:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view=None):
```

- `self` is an instance of request instead of an instance of the permission class
- `request` is an instance of view
- and I had to put view=None because it was crashing with missing parameter errors

Have I configured it wrong somehow?

My `IsEmailVerified` permission used as a default permission has been working as expected for a month, but when adding custom permissions more programmatically I get errors.

```
  File "/app/api/permissions.py", line 50, in has_permission
    user = request.user
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ExampleViewSet' object has no attribute 'user'
```

settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'api.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'api.permissions.IsEmailVerifiedPermission',
    ),
    . . .
}
```

permissions.py

```
class IsEmailVerifiedPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view=None):
        return request.user.email_verified

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view=None, obj=None):
        return request.user.email_verified


class UserCreated(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view=None):
        # While debugging the parameters don't line up:
        # self is an instance of request
        # request is an instance of view
        # and I had to put view=None because it was crashing with missing parameter errors

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view=None, obj=None):
        # See above issue


class CanGloballyEdit(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view=None):
        # See above issue

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view=None, obj=None):
        # See above issue
```

views/example.py

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    
    def get_permissions(self):
        default_permissions = super(viewsets.GenericViewSet, self).get_permissions()
        if self.action == 'list':
            return [CanGloballyEdit] + default_permissions
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return [UserCreated] + default_permissions
        if self.action in ('update', 'partial_update'):
            return [UserCreated | CanGloballyEdit] + default_permissions
        return default_permissions
```

Comment: I haven't used DRF in a while, but the parameters being as you describe suggest that the method is being called directly on a class instead of an instance. Make sure you aren't passing a class to something that's expecting an instance of that class.

Comment: @Carcigenicate This was exactly the answer, thank you. Would you like me to copy/paste what you said to a new answer and mark it as the accepted answer, or do you want to go make one?

Comment: My comment isn't really an answer, so if you want to self-answer with the solution, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Carcigenicate, we realized I needed to provide permission class instances for this scenario.

So `CanGloballyEdit()` instead of `CanGloballyEdit`

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    
    def get_permissions(self):
        default_permissions = super(viewsets.GenericViewSet, self).get_permissions()
        if self.action == 'list':
            return [CanGloballyEdit()] + default_permissions
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return [UserCreated()] + default_permissions
        if self.action in ('update', 'partial_update'):
            return [(UserCreated | CanGloballyEdit)()] + default_permissions
        return default_permissions
```